# How to read all files with different extensions from git repository?

Tags: java, gitlab-api

How to read all the files with a different extension (say .txt, .yml, etc) from the GitLab repository?

I'm using `GitLabApi` and below is the code that I have done so far. This is basically fetching a single file.

```
public class GitLabRepoService {

    @Value("${gitlab.accessToken}")
    private String strAccessToken;

    @Value("${gitlab.perfScript.projectId}")
    private String strProjectId;

    public RepositoryFile readFilesFromGitLabRepo(String hostUrl,String fileName,String strBranch) throws Exception {
        GitLabApi gitLabApi = new GitLabApi(hostUrl, strAccessToken);
        gitLabApi.setIgnoreCertificateErrors(true);
        gitLabApi.getRepositoryFileApi().
        return gitLabApi.getRepositoryFileApi().getFile(strProjectId, fileName, strBranch);

    }

}
```

Comment: I need to get a complete file list of ALL files in the repository, not just the ones in the root directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to request is the repositories tree if I understand correctly. For that you should use this endpoint https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repositories.html

I could not properly test it but according to the docs it looks like `RepositoryApi.getTree()` is what you are looking for [getTree()](https://appdoc.app/artifact/org.gitlab4j/gitlab4j-api/4.6.6/org/gitlab4j/api/RepositoryApi.html#getTree-java.lang.Integer-)

Comment: Thank you. yes I was looking for this